# XCode: run iOS app without Debugger attached

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I'm currently trying to test my App on an iOS Device without having a debugger attached. This is in order to test the PLCrashReporter library, because the debugger catches all crashes instead of the CrashReporter doing it.

Things I tried:

- Run in release mode
- disable Breakpoints

There must be a way to achieve this without having to export the IPA file and installing it manually. I'd like to see NSLog messages and I can't with the IPA file.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually quite simple. Build and run the app through Xcode. Then stop the app from Xcode so the app terminates on the device. Now simply run the app on the device, without Xcode.

As mentioned, use the Xcode Organizer to view the device's console while you run the app.

Comment: Thank you, that was really kind of obvious! I wonder where my head was the last two days... One thing to add: In order to view the NSLog messages I need to open "Console" instead of Device Logs, because you'll only find crashes there.

Comment: Install iPhone configuration utility found at http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US and plug your iPhone with computer. You can see all your log on iPhone configuration utility.

Answer (score 0):

To view your logs when running your app on your device open the organizer in xcode and look for device logs tab. All logs will be written there. (regardless if its debug or not)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, simply by running the application and opening `Organizer` from Xcode.
(Window -> Organizer).

There, you can actually see every log that is recorded without running it thorough xcode! (look for Device logs)

Goodluck

Comment: The answer you have post is works in older version of Xcode however for latest version of Xcode like 7, 8 is not working the way you explained.